# Two different formats in the datagridview column

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a **column** called **Discount Value** in **DataGridView** which has **two different formats** namely **Currency** and **Percentage**.

Is it possible to do a **different format** on one **column** of the **DataGridView**? Thanks.

I tried using the code below but the output is not as expected. Problem in **RegulerDiscount_DataGridView_CellFormatting**

```
namespace WinFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            List<RegulerDiscountModel> regulerDiscountModelList = new List<RegulerDiscountModel>();

            RegulerDiscountModel regulerDiscountModel1 = new RegulerDiscountModel();
            regulerDiscountModel1.RegulerDiscountID = 1;
            regulerDiscountModel1.RegulerDiscountProductId = 1;
            regulerDiscountModel1.RegulerDiscountProductName = "Product 1";
            regulerDiscountModel1.RegulerDiscountName = "Disc1";
            regulerDiscountModel1.RegulerDiscountValue = 1000;
            regulerDiscountModel1.RegulerDiscountStrTypeId = "Rp";
            regulerDiscountModelList.Add(regulerDiscountModel1);

            RegulerDiscountModel regulerDiscountModel2 = new RegulerDiscountModel();
            regulerDiscountModel2.RegulerDiscountID = 1;
            regulerDiscountModel2.RegulerDiscountProductId = 1;
            regulerDiscountModel2.RegulerDiscountProductName = "Product 1";
            regulerDiscountModel2.RegulerDiscountName = "Disc2";
            regulerDiscountModel2.RegulerDiscountValue = 2000;
            regulerDiscountModel2.RegulerDiscountStrTypeId = "Rp";
            regulerDiscountModelList.Add(regulerDiscountModel2);

            RegulerDiscountModel regulerDiscountModel3 = new RegulerDiscountModel();
            regulerDiscountModel3.RegulerDiscountID = 1;
            regulerDiscountModel3.RegulerDiscountProductId = 1;
            regulerDiscountModel3.RegulerDiscountProductName = "Product 1";
            regulerDiscountModel3.RegulerDiscountName = "Disc3";
            regulerDiscountModel3.RegulerDiscountValue = 10.5;
            regulerDiscountModel3.RegulerDiscountStrTypeId = "%";
            regulerDiscountModelList.Add(regulerDiscountModel3);

            RegulerDiscountModel regulerDiscountModel4 = new RegulerDiscountModel();
            regulerDiscountModel4.RegulerDiscountID = 1;
            regulerDiscountModel4.RegulerDiscountProductId = 1;
            regulerDiscountModel4.RegulerDiscountProductName = "Product 1";
            regulerDiscountModel4.RegulerDiscountName = "Disc4";
            regulerDiscountModel4.RegulerDiscountValue = 20.1;
            regulerDiscountModel4.RegulerDiscountStrTypeId = "%";
            regulerDiscountModelList.Add(regulerDiscountModel4);

            CtechGroupedDataGridView.DataSource = regulerDiscountModelList;
            CtechGroupedDataGridView.CellFormatting += CtechGroupedDataGridView_CellFormatting;
        }

        private void CtechGroupedDataGridView_CellFormatting(object? sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.RowIndex <= CtechGroupedDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1)
                {
                    DataGridViewRow row = CtechGroupedDataGridView.CurrentRow;
                    if (row != null)
                    {
                        // ID ProductId ProductName DiscountName DiscountValue DiscountType
                        // 0  1         2           3            4             5

                        if (row.Cells[4].Value != null && row.Cells[5].Value != null)
                        {
                            String? strDiscountValue = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                            String? strDiscountType = row.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
                            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(strDiscountValue) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(strDiscountType))
                            {
                                switch (strDiscountType)
                                {
                                    case "Rp":
                                        CtechGroupedDataGridView[4, e.RowIndex].Style.Format = "N0";
                                        break;

                                    case "%":
                                        CtechGroupedDataGridView[4, e.RowIndex].Style.Format = "P1";
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Current Output:
[image]

When I clicked on DataGridView, I get Output as follows:
[image]

Expected output:
[image]

Grouped DataGridView (it's works)

```
namespace WinFormsApp1
{
    public partial class CtechGroupedDataGridView : DataGridView
    {
        public CtechGroupedDataGridView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DoubleBuffered = true;
            GridColor = Color.LightGray;
            BackgroundColor = SystemColors.Control;
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
            SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
            ColumnGroupEnabled = new int[] { 1, 2};

            ClearSelection();
        }

        protected override void OnDataBindingComplete(DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnDataBindingComplete(e);

            // Fit columns
            int columnsWidth = 0;
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in this.Columns)
            {
                if (column.Visible)
                {
                    columnsWidth += column.Width;
                }
            }

            if (columnsWidth < this.Width)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < this.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    this.Columns[i].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
                }
                this.Columns[this.Columns.Count - 1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < this.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    this.Columns[i].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < this.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                int column = this.Columns[i].Width;
                this.Columns[i].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;
                this.Columns[i].Width = column;
                this.Columns[i].HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            }

            ClearSelection();
        }


        protected override void OnCellFormatting(DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs args)
        {
            // Call home to base
            base.OnCellFormatting(args);

            // First row always displays
            if (args.RowIndex == 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (IsRepeatedCellValue(args.RowIndex, args.ColumnIndex))
            {
                args.Value = string.Empty;
                args.FormattingApplied = true;
            }
        }

        private bool IsRepeatedCellValue(int rowIndex, int colIndex)
        {
            if (ColumnGroupEnabled.Contains(colIndex))
            {
                DataGridViewCell currCell = Rows[rowIndex].Cells[colIndex];
                DataGridViewCell prevCell = Rows[rowIndex - 1].Cells[colIndex];

                if (currCell.Value != null && prevCell.Value != null)
                {
                    if ((currCell.Value == prevCell.Value) || (currCell.Value.ToString() == prevCell.Value.ToString()))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        public int[] ColumnGroupEnabled { get; set; }


        protected override void OnCellPainting(DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs args)
        {
            base.OnCellPainting(args);

            // Keep first and last row to visible
            if (args.RowIndex >= 0 && args.RowIndex < RowCount - 1)
            {
                args.AdvancedBorderStyle.Bottom = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None;
            }

            // Ignore column and row headers and first row
            if (args.RowIndex < 1 || args.ColumnIndex < 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (IsRepeatedCellValue(args.RowIndex, args.ColumnIndex))
            {
                args.AdvancedBorderStyle.Top = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None;
            }
            else
            {
                args.AdvancedBorderStyle.Top = AdvancedCellBorderStyle.Top;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Reguler DiscountModel (it's works)

```
public class RegulerDiscountModel
{
    public RegulerDiscountModel()
    {
    }

    [DisplayName("ID")]
    public int RegulerDiscountID
    {
        get; set;
    }

    [DisplayName("Product Id")]
    public int RegulerDiscountProductId
    {
        get; set;
    }

    [DisplayName("Product Name")]
    public String? RegulerDiscountProductName
    {
        get; set;
    }

    [DisplayName("Discount Name")]
    public String? RegulerDiscountName
    {
        get; set;
    }

    [DisplayName("Discount Value")]
    public double RegulerDiscountValue
    {
        get; set;
    }

    [DisplayName("Discount Type")]
    public String? RegulerDiscountStrTypeId
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not be using `CurrentRow` in that event handler. The event provides the row index and the column index of the cell being formatted. Not sure whether that will address your issue but it is something to correct regardless. Also, you tell us what the expected output is but not what the actual output is.

Comment: Also, I have to wonder why you're converting values to `strings` when they are not `strings`. If the data is type `double`, that's the type you should be using. Don't convert numbers, etc, to `strings` unless you actually need a `string`, e.g. for display.

Comment: It doesnt seem like yolu have properly framed the issue.  A `Discount Amount` and `Discount Percent` is not 2 different formats, but 2 different *values` - entirely different numbers.  In that case make it 2 different columns

Comment: @jmcilhinney, I added a screenshot of the output that didn't meet expectations.

Comment: Firstly, using a "P" format specifier is wrong for what you want. That will multiply a number by 100 and append a percentage symbol, e.g. the value 0.5 will be formatted as "50 %". That doesn't seem to be what you want. It seems like you want "N0" for the currency values and "N1" or "F1" for the percentage values.

Comment: Secondly, you should make the change I suggested earlier and, if it still doesn't work, you need to actually debug that event handler. Set a breakpoint at the top and step through the code to see exactly what it does and where exactly that isn't what you expect. You should ALWAYS have already done that before posting a question and be able to explain to us what that difference is.

Comment: I notice that you're also not using `e.ColumnIndex` in that event handler, which is a mistake. That event is going to be raised at least once for every cell, but generally more than that. The idea is that you only form that cell that is currently being formatted. Because you're not checking the column index, you're going to format the same cell at least six times, because you have six columns. If you only want to format one column, check that the cell being formatted is in that column.

Comment: The reason you should not be using `CurrentRow` is that that is the row that currently contains the caret, but that is not necessarily the row containing the cell that is being formatted. `e.RowIndex` and `e.ColumnIndex` tell you exactly what cell is being formatted so use them to access that cell and any other cells in the same row or the same column.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, thanks for point out. I resolved problem with replace  "P1" with "F1" and replace DataGridViewRow row = CtechGroupedDataGridView.CurrentRow; with  DataGridViewRow row = CtechGroupedDataGridView[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].OwningRow;

Comment: As another commenter stated, you shouldn't combine _Discount Amount_ values and _Discount Percentage_ values in the same column. You've already added another column named _Discount Type_, so you're not saving any space within the _DataGridView_. Therefore, what's the purpose? The current approach makes it difficult to comprehend the data.

Comment: @Tudeschizieuinchid I know, usually in one product there is one discount and it's in the form of a percentage.

I'm building a discount app using java cards, aiming to attract a large number of users using a multiple discount strategy. The amount of the discount depends on the membership type, the number of purchase points, or the celebration of certain special days.

In one product can get more than one discount. And the discount can be a percentage of the item's price or a certain amount of money, or a mixture of the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void CtechGroupedDataGridView_CellFormatting(object? sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.RowIndex <= CtechGroupedDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1)
        {
            // Bug in here
            //DataGridViewRow row = CtechGroupedDataGridView.CurrentRow;
            DataGridViewRow row = CtechGroupedDataGridView[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].OwningRow;

            if (row != null)
            {
                // ID ProductId ProductName DiscountName DiscountValue DiscountType
                // 0  1         2           3            4             5

                if (row.Cells[4].Value != null && row.Cells[5].Value != null)
                {
                    String? strDiscountValue = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                    String? strDiscountType = row.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(strDiscountValue) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(strDiscountType))
                    {
                        switch (strDiscountType)
                        {
                            case "Rp":
                                CtechGroupedDataGridView[4, e.RowIndex].Style.Format = "N0";
                                break;

                            case "%":
                                // Bug in here
                                //CtechGroupedDataGridView[4, e.RowIndex].Style.Format = "P1";
                                CtechGroupedDataGridView[4, e.RowIndex].Style.Format = "F1";
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Output

[image]